# How to stop the search in CP Optimizer if the upper bound doesn't get better after x seconds

Tags: optimization, ilog, cp-optimizer

I'm wondering if there exists a way in CP Optimizer 12.10 to stop the search if the upper bound (of a minimization problem) doesn't get better after "x" seconds. This would be especially helpful when trying to solve a difficult instance of an NP-Hard problem and the search is stuck in one incumbent solution.

I know there exist some parameters to control the search as `cp.param.TimeLimit` (I'm using that) or `cp.param.FailLimit` but that is not that I need for my problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is use a main block (flow control) if you rely on the OPL API and in this main block you give a time limit of x seconds, then you get the bound and the current objective, you save them if you think you should go further or stop if you're ok with the solution.

Let me share a full example out of the lifegame example in the OPL product. And remember John Conway once again.

```
using CP;





int n=20;
int Half=n div 2;
range FirstHalf = 1..Half;
range LastHalf = n-Half+1..n; 
range States = 0..1;
range Bord = 0..(n+1);
range Interior = 1..n;

range obj = 0..(n*n);

tuple neighbors {
   int row;
   int col;
}

{neighbors} Neighbor = 
  {<(-1),(-1)>,<(-1),0>,<(-1),1>,<0,(-1)>,<0,1>,<1,(-1)>,<1,0>,<1,1>};

dvar int Life[Bord][Bord] in States;
dvar int Obj in obj;

dvar int x[0..(n+2)*(n+2)-1];

maximize Obj;

subject to {

forall(i,j in Bord) Life[i][j]==x[i*(n+2)+j];

  //ct1:
    Obj == sum( i , j in Bord ) 
      Life[i][j];

  forall( i , j in Interior ) {
    ct21: 
      2*Life[i][j] - sum( nb in Neighbor ) 
        Life[i+nb.row][j+nb.col] <= 0;
    ct22:
      3*Life[i][j] + sum( nb in Neighbor ) 
        Life[i+nb.row][j+nb.col] <= 6;
    forall( ordered n1 , n2 , n3 in Neighbor ) {
      ct23: 
        -Life[i][j]+Life[i+n1.row][j+n1.col]
                   +Life[i+n2.row][j+n2.col]
                   +Life[i+n3.row][j+n3.col]
        -sum( nb in Neighbor : nb!=n1 && nb!=n2 && nb!=n3 ) 
          Life[i+nb.row][j+nb.col] <= 2;
    }
  }
  forall( j in Bord ) {
    ct31:
      Life[0][j] == 0;
    ct32:  
      Life[j][0] == 0;
    ct33:  
      Life[j][n+1] == 0;
    ct34:  
      Life[n+1][j] == 0;
  }
  forall( i in Bord : i<n ) {
    ct41:
      Life[i][1]+Life[i+1][1]+Life[i+2][1] <= 2;
    ct42:
      Life[1][i]+Life[1][i+1]+Life[1][i+2] <= 2;
    ct43:
      Life[i][n]+Life[i+1][n]+Life[i+2][n] <= 2;
    ct44:
      Life[n][i]+Life[n][i+1]+Life[n][i+2] <= 2;
  }
  ct5:
    sum( i in FirstHalf , j in Bord ) 
      Life[i][j] >= 
    sum( i in LastHalf , j in Bord ) 
      Life[i][j];
  ct6:
    sum( i in Bord , j in FirstHalf ) 
      Life[i][j] >= 
    sum( i in Bord , j in LastHalf ) 
      Life[i][j];   
}


main
{

thisOplModel.generate();
cp.param.timelimit=10;
var obj=0;
var bound=0;
var oldobj=0;
var oldbound=0;

while (1==1)
{
  cp.solve();
  obj=cp.getObjValue();
  bound=cp.getObjBound();
  writeln("bound and obj =",bound," ",obj);
  if (Opl.abs((oldobj-oldbound-obj+bound))<=0) break;
  oldobj=obj;
  oldbound=bound;
}  

}
```

which gives

```
bound and obj =398 181
bound and obj =398 180
bound and obj =398 180
// Script execution finished with status 1.
```